# How to get rid of akka AskTimeout Exception in play application while Performance test

Tags: playframework-2.0, jmeter, akka, performance-testing

I am running a web application on play 2.0.4 and now its in the performance testing phase.
Requirement is 1000 users/hr logged in the web app.

Currently i am facing issue with just 100 threads introduced in system via Jmeter as the perf tool.
Getting 20-25 http failures for samplers on Jmeter, each time i run for 100 threads.
And in play logs i see `AskTimeout`. Also, no of http failures are equal to no of Ask Timeout in play logs.

```
Jmeter Sampler error-
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 0
```

Play logs:

> 2013-04-07 09:49:08,740 ERROR
>   [play-akka.actor.promises-dispatcher-493] play: Cannot invoke the
>   action, eventually got an error:
>   Thrown(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out)

See the akka configuration below for 50 Jmeter threads (successful run).

How to tune it further for 100 threads, so that i don't see the AskTimeout exception?

```
play {

    akka {
        event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
        loglevel = INFO

        actor {

            deployment {

                /actions {
                    router = round-robin
                    nr-of-instances = 1000
                }

               /promises {
                    router = round-robin
                    nr-of-instances = 1000
                }
              }

            retrieveBodyParserTimeout = 5 second

            actions-dispatcher = {
                fork-join-executor {
                    parallelism-factor = 100
                    parallelism-max = 200
                 }
                throughput = 100
                mailbox-capacity = 100
                mailbox-type =""
            }

            promises-dispatcher = {
                fork-join-executor {
                   parallelism-factor = 4
                  parallelism-max = 100
             }
                throughput = 100
                }

           websockets-dispatcher = {
              fork-join-executor {
                 parallelism-factor = 2.0
                parallelism-max = 100
           }
                throughput = 100
           }

          default-dispatcher = {
             fork-join-executor {
                parallelism-factor = 2.0
               parallelism-max = 100
             }
                throughput = 100
           }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need all those threads? do you have hundreds of cores?

Comment: Well, 100 threads in one jmeter run here means , 100 logins to the web app, in one run.

Comment: Are you running JMeter on the same machine you're running the webapp on? And in your config, you've configured to use hundreds of threads for play, I just want to know why you need hundreds of threads for Play.

Comment: servers for jmeter and play app are different but close. Will surely try to run them on same server as ur suggestion.

Comment: Also, regarding the play threads- earlier config for action and promis dispatcher were- factor: 2.0, parallelism-max: 50, but this config could not help more than 10 Jmeter threads, so had to increase the play threads. Though a little more knowledge about the play threads can help a lot.

Comment: Are you doing blocking in your play requests?

Comment: The thread dumps show Blocking requests, and its a play server is talking to a weblogic server.

Comment: Did some logging changes in the app, we see lot of improvement in the response time, but Ask Timeout is still there.

Comment: Make your requests async instead. That should improve throughput.